# Finding how many hex values a string containing hex and random string

Tags: text-processing, sed, string, hex

I have the file `~/dummy_hex.txt` containing hex and random string:

```
\x12\xA1\xF1\xE3somegibberigh
```

I want to count how many hex values (groups of \x^hex_digit^^hex_digit^) the string above has. In the example above I want the commands to run to return the number `4`.

In other words I want to type over my terminal:

```
command ^file_having hex^
```

And return the value 4

So far I tried to do that with:

```
sed 's/[^\x[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]]//g' dummy_hex.txt | awk '{ print length }'
```

But somehow seems to return wrong result because of regex misstype. Can you tell me how to use full PCRE compartible regex with sed in order to do that?

Alternatively I want to count how many hex values my string contains.

## Edit 1

An another approach is to count the `\x` string occurences but that may count any stray `\x` that may not be followed with a value indicating a hexadimal string.

```
 sed 's/[^\x]//g' dummy_hex.txt | awk '{ print length }'
```

Further more I tried to do that with `-r` option that enables PCRE:

```
 sed -r 's/^\\x[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]]/g' dummy_hex.txt | awk '{ print length }'
```

But I get the error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Just for clarification: how many bytes are there in this file?

Comment: The `wc -c` says 30 bytes.

Comment: So "hex values" really means "groups of <backslash><x><hex digit><hex digit>". Because there is no such thing as a "hex value."

Comment: hop Yes hex value means that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `grep` that supports Extended Regular Expressions and the `-o` option:

```
grep -Eo '\\x[[:xdigit:]]{2}' input | wc -l
```

To fit the requirement of `command filename`:

```
function counthex() {
  grep -Eo '\\x[[:xdigit:]]{2}' "$1" | wc -l
}
```

As:

```
counthex input
```

Answer (score 1):

If you count the characters without hex:

```
$ sed 's/\([^\]*\)\\x[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]/\1/g' dummy_hex.txt | LC_ALL=C wc -c
14
```

And substract that from the whole file count:

```
$ <dummy_hex.txt wc -c
30
```

You could get the count of hex characters (times 4). In one script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(sed 's/\([^\]*\)\\x[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]/\1/g' dummy_hex.txt | wc -c)
b=$(<dummy_hex.txt wc -c )
count=$(( (b-a)/4 ))
echo "$count"
```

Prints:

```
$ ./script
4
```

Remember that wc counts bytes (not locale dependent characters).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input
bla\x12\xA1\xF1
\xE3bla
$ perl -nle '$c++ while m/\\x[[:xdigit:]]/g; END { print $c }' input
4
$
```

Basically loop without printing over the input (`perldoc perlrun`), increment a counter for each match, and then print that count.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the installed perl to do that:

```
perl -lne 'print my $c = () = /\\x[[:xdigit:]]+/' dummy_hex.txt
```

That offer a quick and easy oneliner in case you do not want to write a script (eg. on a instruction sheet that will contain commands to execute.)

Comment: that's going to produce a per-line tally, not a total count